# Changing value of a Node

Tags: java

I currently have LinkedStack with three Nodes with values in it. The values were created by using the push method I created in the class that is noted below. My question is after I pushed :"1,2,3"; I have a list of 3 elements which in my assignment need to be change in order from the top Node to the bottom using a condition while(current != null) etc. But my question is how do I manage to change the element values without using Arraylist library or such methods that are used to ease out those kind of commands just with setMethods on the main class for example this is what I got done but obviously it wont work since its just referring to itself not changing anything. What I got done is by the "Where the code should change the values of the values that you already pushed in the List", line. Could someone explain what am I doing wrong on that line? I tried using the list object on the main class to call the LinearNode class methods but it wont let me since it expects for given variable current to be equal to the object. 
Bless you.

## LinearNode class

```
public class LinearNode<T> 
{

    private LinearNode<T> next; //se guarda la direccion del Nodo
    private T element;          //Lista vacia

    public LinearNode()
{
    next = null;
    element = null;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Creates a node storing the specified element.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinearNode (T elem, LinearNode reference)
    {
    next = reference;
    element = elem;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the node that follows this one.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public LinearNode<T> getNext()
    {
    return next;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets the node that follows this one.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setNext (LinearNode<T> node)
    {
    next = node;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the element stored in this node.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public T getElement()//asigna valor
    {
    return element;
    }

    public void setElement(T elem)
    {

        element = elem;


    }



    }
```

## LinkedStack class

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements Stack<T> {


private int count;
private LinearNode<T> top; //referencia del Nodo ( direccion) 

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Creates an empty stack using the default capacity.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public LinkedStack()
{
count = 0;
top = null;

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Removes the element at the top of this stack and returns a
// reference to it. Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the
// stack contains no elements.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

public LinearNode getLinearNode(){
    return top;
}

    @Override
    public boolean IsEmpty()

    {
        if(top == null)
        {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        }
        return top == null;
    }



    @Override
    public void Push(T element)
{

     LinearNode<T> current = new LinearNode<>(element, top);
     current.setNext(top);top a la variable de referencia next
     top = current;
     count++;


}

    @Override 
    public T Pop() 
{


    T result;
    System.out.println("Lets pop the top element!");

   if(count == 0)
   {
    System.out.println("Stack is empty");   
   }


    result = top.getElement();
    top = top.getNext(); 
    count--;
    System.out.println("The element that we have poped is: " + "'" + result + "'" + "\n");

    return result;


}

    @Override
    public String toString()
{

String result = "";
LinearNode current = top;
System.out.print("<top of stack-->" + "\n");
while (current != null)
{

result += "[" + current.getElement() + "]" + "\n"; 
current = current.getNext();
}
return result  + "<--bottom of stack>" + "\n";

}

    @Override
    public T Peek() {
        System.out.println("Lets peek the top element!");
        if(count == 0)
        {
         System.out.println("Peek failed stack is empty");
        }
        System.out.println("The element that we have peeked is: " + "[" + top.getElement()+ "]" +"\n");
        return top.getElement();

    }

    @Override
    public int Size() {
        if(count != 0)
        {
        System.out.println("Let's check the size of the list!");
        System.out.println("The size of the list is: "+ "'" + count + "'" + "\n");
        }
        if(count == 0)
        {
          System.out.println("The size of the list is...Woah.");  
          System.out.println("The list size is now: " + "'" + count + "'"  + "\n" + "Push more elements!");
        }

        return count;
    }






    }
```

## Main class

```
public class LSmain {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
     LinkedStack<Integer> list = new LinkedStack<>();   
     System.out.println("Let's make a List!");
     System.out.println("Push 3 times.");
     System.out.println("Check the size.");
     System.out.println("Peek the top element.");
     System.out.println("Pop three times.");
     System.out.println("The size now should be zero!" + "\n");
     list.Push(1);
     list.Push(2);
     list.Push(3);
     list.Size();
     System.out.println(list.toString());
     System.out.println("Change values");




     #//#
```

### Where the code should change the values of the values that you already pushed in the List

```
     LinearNode<Integer>current;
     current = list.getLinearNode();

     while(current != null)
     {
     current.setNext(current);
     current.setElement(5);
     }
     #//#   

     System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code comments say that `getLinearNode` removes the element at the top of the stack and returns a reference to it, but you're not actually removing the top stack element from the stack.  I'm assuming that your implementation is correct and that your comments are incorrect or that I'm misinterpreting your comments.  Otherwise, `LinkedStack` will need a method that returns a reference to the top of the stack without modifying the stack in order for you to be able to loop through the stack nodes.

```
LinkedStack stack;
LinearNode current = stack.getLinearNode();
while(current != null) {
    current.setElement(T); // I don't know what T is supposed to be here
    current = current.getNext();
}
```

Comment: Your exactly right sir. Yesterday I don't know why I erased the main class, did it again and it worked same with the getter method that I have but I had a big mistake on the while condition I wasn't setting an element first the moving to the next Node. Somehow using LinearNode<T> current; current = list.getLinearNode(); worked on the process I don't know why it marked it wrong but it worked afterwards. I got help from a friend and all he did was do the same thing but in other terms and commented on what I wrong and when I deleted the comments it worked. Thank you sir for your help. Bless you.